# ScrollView inside of TouchablewithoutFeedback

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to make a text reader. It has Header and a content with mass characters, so it's required scrollview to let the user read all the staff.

But now what confused me is, I am trying to hide the header when people press the screen for the short period, and when people scroll down, which has finger touch the screen and move a bit, header still there.

Right now what I tried is,

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{padding: 40}} onPress={()=>this.pressScreen()} pressRetentionOffset={{top:1,left:1,bottom:1,right:1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{width: screen.width,
      height:screen.height*0.8}}>
        <Text>{this.state.data.chptTitle}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.data.chptContent}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

but clearly it doesn't work becuase pressRetentionOffset cannot work with scrollView.
What should I do? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not wrap it on an onPress. I would put the ScrollView as parent and then wrap all the Text within in a parent Text, then use the `onPress` of the parent `<Text>`. Like this:

```
  <ScrollView style={{padding: 40, width: screen.width,
  height:screen.height*0.8}}>
    <Text onPress={()=>this.pressScreen()}>
      <Text>{this.state.data.chptTitle}</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.data.chptContent}</Text>
    </Text>
  </ScrollView>
```

To me personally, it doesn't make sense to make a `ScrollView` be the child of a `Touchable*`

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to make something like Kindle reader, when I touch the screen for a short period, it will hide the header and footer. Or I can move my finger on the screen to scroll the page in order to read the book. This is a nice solution, thank you.

Comment: Nice @Ethan, its my pleasure.